# Data driven tests generated in ClassInitialize: no longer working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest, data-driven-tests

I have upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012.

In my unit test project, I have a [ClassInitialize] method which generates a CSV file which I then feed into a data-driven [TestMethod] using [DataSource] connected to the CSV.

This works great in Visual Studio 2010.

I cannot get this to work in Visual Studio 2012.

It seems that in VS2012 the MS test runner requires the file connected to the [DataSource] to already exist otherwise none of the tests will run. If I create the CSV myself, the data-driven tests run, but they do not pick up the data created in [ClassInitialize]: it seems that the list of tests from the [DataSource] is evaluated BEFORE [ClassInitialize] runs.

Is there a workaround?

---

This is a minimal project that reproduces the problem. For me, this succeeds in VS2010 but fails in VS2012.

**TestProject.cs**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class DataDrivenUnitTest
    {
        private static bool _classInitializeCalled;
        private static int _testCount;

        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        {
            // Generate the csv list of tests
            //TestContext = testContext;
            _classInitializeCalled = true;
            string testDirectory;
            testDirectory = testContext.DeploymentDirectory;
            using (var f = new StreamWriter(testDirectory + @"\" + "TestList.csv"))
            {
                f.WriteLine("TestName");
                f.WriteLine("TestA");
                f.WriteLine("TestB");
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [DataSource("CsvTestData32")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            _testCount++;
            var testName = TestContext.DataRow["TestName"];
            Debug.Print("Test {0}: {1}", _testCount, testName);
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanup()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(_classInitializeCalled);
            Assert.AreEqual(_testCount, 2);
            Debug.Print("Tests completed: Tests run {0}", _testCount);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case 'run test as 32-bit' is the default setting; this may be changed under -

- in VS2012: TEST > TestSettings > Default Processor Architecture
- in VS2010 Right-click Solution explorer 'Solution items' > Add > New Item > Test Settings, then,
- VS2010 main menu > Tests > Edit Test Settings > Hosts > Run tests in 32 bit or 64 bit process.

If you use 64-bit, use [DataSource("CsvTestData64")], and you may need to install the [MS Access 64-bit ODBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). The easiest way is to stick with 32-bit.

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </configSections>

  <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="CsvTestData32" connectionString="CsvConn32" dataTableName="`TestList.csv`" dataAccessMethod="Sequential" />
      <add name="CsvTestData64" connectionString="CsvConn64" dataTableName="`TestTest.csv`" dataAccessMethod="Sequential" />
    </dataSources>
  </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CsvConn32" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};.\;Extensions=csv;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
    <add name="CsvConn64" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};Dbq=.\;Extensions=csv" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A guess. Debug the test, make sure testContext.DeploymentDirectory, is teh same place as where you are puuting teh file manually.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the MSTest adapter in Visual Studio 2012. Can you submit it at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio ?

Comment: has this been fixed yet?

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/4a8403a2-b495-4120-aad3-0d0becc7e45e/

Comment: Also this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025719/why-does-data-driven-unit-test-fail-in-vs2012-when-it-worked-fine-in-vs2010

Answer (score 4):

[MSTestHacks](https://github.com/Thwaitesy/MSTestHacks) might help.

It allows an `IEnumerable` on your test class to be used as the `DataSource` for your `TestMethod`.

From the website:

Runtime data source: your test class MUST inherit from `TestBase`:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 : TestBase
{ }
```

Create a property, field or method that returns an `IEnumerable`

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 : TestBase
{
    private IEnumerable<int> Stuff
    {
        get
        {
            //This could do anything, fetch a dynamic list from anywhere....
            return new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        }
    }
}
```

Add the `DataSource` attribute to your test method, pointing back to the `IEnumerable` name created earlier. This needs to be fully qualified.

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("Namespace.UnitTest1.Stuff")]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var number = this.TestContext.GetRuntimeDataSourceObject<int>();

    Assert.IsNotNull(number);
}
```

Comment: only problem with this solution is the `TestBase` requirement, would be nice if `MSTestHacks` authors could find a way to implement this sort of extension without mandating base classes for all test fixtures.